# Factorize $x^8+17x^4+16x^2+17$ by hand

Tags: polynomials, factoring

The correct solution should be
$$(x^2-x+1)(x^2+x+1)(x^4-x^2+17)$$

This is originally posted as a high school entrance exam question, no calculators allowed.

So this is meant to be doable by hard. However, the solution doesn't have any linear factors, making it hard to find a root.

Is there a method to factorize by hand?

---

Edit: It is now answered that substituting $z=x^2$ can make it factorizeable. Then, using $$a^4+a^2+1 = (a^2+a+1)(a^2-a+1)$$

Can further factorize it into the correct solution.

Comment: Well, letting $z=x^2$, the quartic $z^4+17z^2+16z+17$ factors as the product of two quadratics.  That makes the problem tractable.

Comment: The only thing I can see doing is to make the change of variables $y=x^2$ to get a cubic polynomial, but that does not help much. I think this is quite difficult for a high school entrance exam, unless this is one of those special schools.

Comment: @KBS As lulu suggested, make the substitution.  After the rational root test fails, a version of the fundamental theorem of algebra assures that *any* polynomial can be factored as the product of linear and irreducible quadratic polynomials.  So, assume that it can be factored as $(z^2 + bz + c)(z^2 + dz + e)$.  Expand the polynomial and compare coefficients.  It is actually quite tractable, if a little tedious.

Comment: When you don't see any simple $\alpha$ such that $P(\alpha)=0$, it's useful to try imaginary numbers. And usually the correct one is one among: $$\omega_1=\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{3}i}{2},\quad \omega_2=\frac{1\pm \sqrt{3}i}{2}$$

These are the solutions to $x^2+x+1=0$ and $x^2-x+1=0$ respectively. 

The reason why these probably come in handy is that $\omega_1^3=1$ and $\omega_2^3=-1$. So when you're checking if any of these make $P(x)=0$, don't use the exact value but instead utilize the $\omega_1^2+\omega_1+1=0$ and $\omega_1^3=1$ to simplify.

Comment: @Saturday I am not sure that this is a really great approach, as it is a kind of "mathematics by psychology" (e.g. you are trying to exploit the psychology of the question author in order to deduce a factor).  It is not really a generalizable technique, as the set of polynomials with roots among the roots of unity is pretty small. :/

Comment: @XanderHenderson I did not see the previous comment and I misread one exponent. But yes, what you are suggesting is fine, albeit a bit complicated for a high-schooler.

Comment: @XanderHenderson You're right, this approach only works because it is for a high school entrance exam. Based on my experience, it's quite common.

Comment: @KBS I think that anyone who is being taught to factor polynomials should know about the FTA, and ought to be introduced to the notion of "matching coefficients" (as this is an *incredibly* general technique in mathematics:  assume that you have a solution of a given form, and follow the consequences of that assumption).  As to this being on a high school entrance exam, I am assuming that "high school" means something different here than it does in my own American context (e.g. this is an entrance exam to a high school for "gifted" students, or students which have been "tracked" somehow).

Comment: My comment was based on the required mathematical maturity suggested by the question, rather than the reported context of a "high school entrance exam".

Comment: @XanderHenderson Your first method worked. As 17 is a prime, it is easy to guess the coefficients, giving $(z^2+z+1)(z^2-z+17)$.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I am pretty sure that almost no usual/standard high-school student would be able to solve that, except, of course, for a few exceptions. High-school students are just able to solve a bunch of problems they have been exposed too and most of the time lack hindsight and extrapolation skills.

Comment: We're all being very naughty, but it's hard to resist. Using the
factorisation
$$
t^4 + t^2 + 1 = (t^2 + 1)^2 - t^2 = (t^2 + t + 1)(t^2 - t + 1)
$$
with $t = x^2$ and $t = x,$ we get
\begin{align*}
x^8 + 17x^4 + 16x^2 + 17
& = (x^8 + x^4 + 1) + 16(x^4 + x^2 + 1) \\
& = (x^4 + x^2 + 1)(x^4 - x^2 + 17) \\
& = (x^2 + x + 1)(x^2 - x + 1)(x^4 - x^2 + 17).
\end{align*}